# Android / Firebase , get timestamp to date

Tags: java, android, firebase

İ'm developing chat app with android studio / java and using firebase , i'm getting an error while getting server timestamps.

**MY SEND FUNCTİON**

```
    public void send(View v) {
    if (!status) {
        String message = text.getText().toString();
        String senderUID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        HashMap<String, Object> postData = new HashMap<>();
        postData.put("senderID", senderUID);
        postData.put("time",FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
        postData.put("message", message);

        firebaseFirestore.collection("chats").document(id).collection("messages").document()
                .set(postData)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        text.setText("");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(chat.this, "Sunucu Hatası...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    }


}
```

MY GET FUNCTİON

```
    public void dataRead(String id) {
    CollectionReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("chats").document(id).collection("messages");
    docRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {
                        messageFb.clear();
                        dateFb.clear();
                        dateFb.clear();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                            Map<String, Object> data = snapshot.getData();
                            String message = (String) data.get("message");
                            String sender = (String) data.get("senderID");
                            Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) data.get("time");

                            messageFb.add(message);
                            senderFb.add(sender);
                            dateFb.add(timestamp.toDate().toString().substring(11,16)); //ERROR İS HERE
                            chatRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

THERE İS THE SMAPLE ERROR    `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Date com.google.firebase.Timestamp.toDate()' on a null object reference`

When i send a any message in my app , the app is crashing , but when i open again , everythings works fine , just crashing when i send and get new data. ANY İDEAS ?

Comment: It is because the time is null, can you check if the time is stored in database?

Comment: it is not null , when i open the activity again it's not crashing .